# Create CSV and Force to Download

Tags: php, csv, download

I want write a CSV and force to Download it automatically. Bit it only displays the file. My code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');


// open to write

$fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');  

// MS-Excel BOM:

fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));

// write columns

foreach ($columnNames as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields, ';');
}

$exportData  = array (
array($value1, $value2, $value3)
);


foreach ($exportData as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields, ';');
}


fclose($fp);
```

I have tried for hours. Nothing do the job. It will only be displayd.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the file to a zip file and asking your visitors to change their settings so that zip files are automatically downloaded.

https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-browser

Comment: This ist not want I want.